# unable to perform insert and delete in this java program arrayoutofbound errors

Tags: java, arrays

Unable to perform insert and delete in this array program. Please give suggestion. Only `find()` is working.

I tried a temp[] to copy Arr[] and then reference Arr[] to temp[]

full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/CqYHD1L8)

```
public boolean find(int x,int Arr[]){
    for (int y=0;y<Arr.length;y++)
    {
        if(Arr[y]==x) {
            System.out.println(" Found , At Position : " + y);
            return true;
        }       
    }
    System.out.println(" Not Found");      
    return false;
}
public void delete (int x,int Arr[]){
    for (int y :Arr)
    {
        if(Arr[y]==x)
        {
              for (int n=y;n<x;n++)
              {
                  Arr[n]=Arr[n+1];
                  System.out.println("Deleted.");
              }
              x--;
        }
    }
}
public void insert(int x,int Arr[]){
    int temp[]=new int[Arr.length + 1];
    for (int y=0;y<Arr.length;y++)
    {
        temp[y]=Arr[y];
    }
    temp[Arr.length]=x;
    Arr=temp;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `for (int y :Arr)` will do? Debug your application and check the values of `y`. Hint: that's _not_ the array index, so I bet you get the exception in the following `Arr[y]==x`. Also have a look at `insert()`, especially the assignment `Arr=temp`. Do you expect that assignment to be visible outside the method? If so then please revisit the tutorials on method parameters.

Comment: For method insert(), remember that in Java *all* arguments are passed by value, so you need to find another way to change Arr.

Comment: This is not like `javascript` which iterate the index of the array. In Java, you directy get the values in `y`.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:: You have used extended for loop in the wrong way. You should first see how extended for loops work here is the link: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/enhanced-for-loops.html

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class GfG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println();
        int[] Arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        insert(2, Arr);
        Arr = delete(30, Arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arr));
    }

    public static boolean find(int x, int Arr[]) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Arr.length; y++) {
            if (Arr[y] == x) {
                System.out.println(" Found , At Position : " + y);
                return true;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(" Not Found");

        return false;
    }

    public static int[]  delete(int x, int Arr[]) {
        int [] temp = Arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
            if (Arr[i] == x) {
                for (int j = i; j < Arr.length - 1; j++) {
                    Arr[j] = Arr[j + 1];
                }
                temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(Arr, 0, Arr.length-1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static void insert(int x, int Arr[]) {
        int temp[] = new int[Arr.length + 1];
        for (int y = 0; y < Arr.length; y++) {
            temp[y] = Arr[y];
        }
        temp[Arr.length] = x;
        Arr = temp;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has different points of failure, not sure I'll catch them all:

1. Your for-loop in delete is broken; I'm sure you ment `for (int y=0; y<Arr.length; y++)` again. Using `for (int y :Arr)` you assign y to all *elements* of Arr, one after each other.
2. x should be the element that should be deleted. Then I don't know why you decrease x in the end of delete. You have to create a new array with one element less.
3. Java uses *call by reference*, not *call by value*. Therefore assigning x to Arr in add does not change the variable of the calling method. You would have to return the new array and the caller has to use this array instead.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: You mean Java uses call by value, not call by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approch.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
interface ArrayOperation {
boolean find(int x,int Arr[]);
int[] delete(int x,int Arr[]);

int[] insert(int x,int Arr[]);

}

class ArrayExample implements ArrayOperation {
public boolean find(int x,int Arr[]){
    for (int y=0;y<Arr.length;y++)
    {
        if(Arr[y]==x) {
            System.out.println(" Found , At Position : " + y);
            return true;
        }

    }
System.out.println(" Not Found");

return false;}
public int[] delete (int x,int Brr[]){
     int temp[]=new int[Brr.length-1];
    for (int y=0;y<Brr.length;y++){
        if(Brr[y]==x){
              for (int n=y;n<Brr.length-1;n++){
                Brr[n]=Brr[n+1];
                System.out.println("Deleted.");
               }
               for (int k=0;k<temp.length;k++){
                temp[k]=Brr[k];
               }

        }


    }   
return temp;
}
public int [] insert(int x,int Brr[]){
    int temp[]=new int[Brr.length + 1];
    for (int y=0;y<Brr.length;y++){
        temp[y]=Brr[y];
    }
    temp[Brr.length]=x;
    return temp;

}
}


public class ArrayCreateFindDeleteInsert{
 public static void main (String args[]){
 System.out.println("Enter the size of Array :");
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int x=in.nextInt();
 System.out.println("You Choose Size : " + x);
 int Arr[]=new int[x];
 ArrayExample A = new ArrayExample();
 System.out.println("Enter Elements");
 for(int y=0;y<Arr.length;y++){
     int z=in.nextInt();
     Arr[y]=z;
 }
 while(true){
 System.out.print("Your Array : ");
 for(int y=0;y<Arr.length;y++){
     System.out.print(Arr[y]+" ");
     }
 System.out.println("\nSelect an operation : ");
 System.out.println("1. Find : ");
 System.out.println("2. Delete : ");
 System.out.println("3. Insert : ");
 System.out.println("4. Quit : ");
 int p=in.nextInt();
 switch(p){
    case 1: System.out.print("Enter Element: ");
            int t=in.nextInt();
            System.out.print(t);
            A.find(t,Arr);
            break ;
    case 2: System.out.print("Enter Element: ");
            int u=in.nextInt();
            while(A.find(u,Arr)==true){
            Arr=A.delete(u,Arr);
            }
            break ;
    case 3: System.out.print("Enter Element: ");
            int v=in.nextInt();
            System.out.print(v);
            Arr=A.insert(v,Arr);
            System.out.print(" Inserted.");
            break ;
    case 4:
             System.exit(0);

 }
 }
 }
 }
```